# How to get access from cross-site popup to window.opener?

Tags: javascript

I've making a widget and I need to redirect a parent window to certain url, after specific event in popup, whitch base on another domain. How a can do this.

```
window.opener.location.replace(url);
```

Comment: unsafe javascript attempt to access frame with url ))

Comment: That sounds like cross-domain scripting which is going to be prevented by security limitations; or am I reading the question incorrectly?

Comment: I want kmow, can I solve this limitations.

Comment: Strangely, it works for me in Firefox. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You just cannot do that. Cross-site scripting is not allowed in most browsers.

You can, however, communicate with the other window via cross-document messaging described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

The most you can to is to send a message from the popup to the opener and listen for such message in the opener. The opener then has to change its location on its own.

```
// popup:
window.opener.postMessage('replace your location', '*');

// opener:
window.onmessage = function (e) {
  if (e.data === 'replace your location') {
    window.location.replace(...);
  }
};
```

Comment: FYI postMessage doesn't work in IE between popups, even in IE10

Comment: My opener should be on different domain www.mydomain.com . I want to send him some sensitive data. How can I check, if my opener is really www.mydomain.com?

Comment: But `window.opener` itself returning null in my case.. Then how will i post the message.

Answer (score 0):

In certain situations it's possible to do that, but only with different subdomains, not completely different domains. See [Cross site scripting on the same domain, different sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962463/cross-site-scripting-on-the-same-domain-different-sub-domains/3962489#3962489).

But since `postMessage()` is widely available in current browsers, you should always prefer `postMessage()`, as @ian-kuca suggests.