# How to create a pop up browser window that contains a GUI and controls a parent browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way in jquery and/or javascript to create a pop up window that can directly effect a parent window in a browser? In my case I want to set up a GUI in the pop up which can move objects in the parent window left/right/up/down. I also need this to work in a dual monitor setting. Any leads on how to do this would be great!

Comment: Watch out for popup blockers - users tend to hate popups except in very narrow circumstances.

Comment: I doubt if a popup is a good idea. It is very confusing, often blocked, and just not possible on mobile devices. Why not go for the arrow keys in your case?

Comment: I don't think the dual screen has anything to do with JavaScript / jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in the child window can control the parent window by using `parent.` for example:

```
parent.alert("moo");
```

Comment: Neat! I think this is excatly what I need just not sure how to implement. So I would wrap the js I use to effect the parent in a function that creates a child window?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.opener` to interact with the opening window, since it sounds like you want to open a new window. So if you have a javascript function declared in the opening window as

```
 function test(){
    alert("I'm the parent!");
 }
```

you can call it from a popup window by calling

```
window.opener.test();
```

The requirement here is that both the opening window and the open window must be either in the same domain or at least subdomain. If it is the same subdomain, a little work is needed to allow the cross-domain access, which you can read more about here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3962489/1558122.

You would initially open the popup of course by calling `window.open` from the parent, and dual monitor should not affect the behavior here.

Comment: I think this is getting me on the right track as well. I will try a few things and report back.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is probably a dialog, not a window. Windows are cumbersome and require all the HTML a document requires. You could try this jquery plugin: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ . A dialog requires minimal HTML.

I confess I don't know about the dual-monitor thing.