# have few pages on a PHP site powered by ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress

I have a basic wordpress site. What i want is for the user to click on `Add to Cart` button and be taken to the shopping cart flow which is built in ASP.net.

Few Facts:

1. Wordpress site is on server #1 (linux)
2. ASP.net site is on server#2 (windows)

Minimum Features:

1. Be able to keep the same domain name (ie: "www.example.com/" should be the same for both the sites.
2. Possibly some way to share cookies

What i have researched:

1. Using iframes plugin in wordpress. Not sure if want to do this. I would prefer to keep the pages totally seperate. - https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe-less-plugin/

What is the process of having one site use pages from two different servers and the user not know that they are going from one server to another?

Comment: don't keeping the same domain is possible.  I would recommend www.example.com redirects to cart.example.com  the asp.net website.

Comment: @KenTucker I think using a subdomain might be an acceptable compromise. Why can we not have the same domain?

Comment: Maybe with a load balancer you could have each page direct to the right server but that makes things very complicated

Comment: That sounds like things I don't have budget for.

Comment: @KenTucker How will you share user session data?

Comment: WordPress has a good eCommerce plugin called WooCommerce. What benefit are you getting from using an asp.net cart in WordPress?

Comment: If you are using nginx - you can just configure upstream which will proxy all requests to specific path (like /cart) to another server. If you are not using nginx - I guess your webserver should have similar capabilities. Cookies will be shared automatically, because domain will be the same.

Comment: Agree with James Jones. Moreover, how many products r u selling? R u hardcoding these and their `Add to cart` links in your WordPress site? If not, how are you fetching the list of products from ASP.NET site? Assuming that there will be some user management, for customers to login and track their orders etc, how are you sharing these user details and sessions between ASP.NET and WP (if you are sharing it)? Also, if its a "basic" WP site, why not develop it in ASP.NET and keep things simple. By trying to integrate WP and ASP.NET from diff servers you are just increasing the complexity, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I think you needn't consider session or cookie matter, if you just want to combine multiple pages form different web servers. You can use [HttpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) to request other pages and merge to your primary page.

```
            request      +---------+   HttpWebRequest             +--------+
           /home?item=1  |         | http://server/partial-home?  |        |
[browser]  <-----------> | portal  | item=1&user=luffy            | partial|
                         | page    | ---------------------------> | page   |
                         +---------+ <--------------------------- +--------+
                                      (return html string...)
```

That is, you can treat the web page as web api. You can get the view you want. If the partial view has special resources like css, js... etc. Setting the [url rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) on your primary page web server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a sub-domain?

[Cross site scripting on the same domain, different sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962463/cross-site-scripting-on-the-same-domain-different-sub-domains#3962489)

This might work well if you are going the iframe route that you mentioned:

https://johnresig.com/blog/cross-window-messaging/

An iframe plugin could work, but you might trip a lot of your own security rules if you also have a security plugin running.